# PIP install "error: package directory 'X' does not exist"

Tags: python, pip, packaging, easy-install

I am trying to install [this package](https://github.com/TheChymera/RTbatch/tree/e53e419c6a7ea1fc4e3b2de8ffd57478720192ab) via PIP. It gives me the following error:

```
error: package directory 'RTbatch' does not exist
```

I find this weird, because [the relevant `setup.py`](https://github.com/TheChymera/RTbatch/blob/e53e419c6a7ea1fc4e3b2de8ffd57478720192ab/setup.py) does not mention any `packages` variable, but only `py_modules`.

What's wrong? Can you help me out?

Here is the full output of `pip install -e RTbatch`:

```
Obtaining file:///home/chymera/RTbatch
  Running setup.py (path:/home/chymera/RTbatch/setup.py) egg_info for package from file:///home/chymera/RTbatch
    /usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'heywords'
      warnings.warn(msg)

    error: package directory 'RTbatch' does not exist
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    /usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'heywords'

  warnings.warn(msg)

running egg_info

creating RTbatch.egg-info

writing requirements to RTbatch.egg-info/requires.txt

writing RTbatch.egg-info/PKG-INFO

writing top-level names to RTbatch.egg-info/top_level.txt

writing dependency_links to RTbatch.egg-info/dependency_links.txt

writing manifest file 'RTbatch.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found



error: package directory 'RTbatch' does not exist

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /home/chymera/RTbatch
Storing debug log for failure in /home/chymera/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: is this all of your error? please put it all

Comment: this is, in fact, the only error I get. but I pasted the entire console output for your convenience above.

Comment: Could you show us the command you are issuing?

Comment: @enrico.bacis `chymera@laptophost ~ $ pip install -e RTbatch` - I have added this to the description as well.

Comment: Is there any more information in the log?

Comment: That is all. Why is everybody asking? Is something very obviously not there? I was thinking the error already quite specifically states where it fails - but im wondering why it's looking there in the first place :-/

Comment: It installs fine now. Did you make any fix?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`py_modules` takes a list of module names, not files. Your call looks for `RTBatch/py.py` and `RTBatch_cli/py.py`.

Comment: How can i just give it a list of files? I find it a superfluous practice to add one more directory level after the root for small packages :-/

Comment: Just skip the extension.

Comment: The extension of the module. The extraneous `.py` part that is not needed whatsoever and which is the thing that causes the error. That extension.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: So it should be `setup` instead of `setup.py`? (Somebody seems to face the same problem with my package [`hwrt`](https://github.com/MartinThoma/hwrt))

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was about that the folder which I use for installation was corrupted. It was not installed completely. I downloaded it on my laptop and then moved it to the server. But it was broken. so I download it again and everything goes well.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was on Windows and the current directory was in a different drive, `python <full path including drive>/setup.py install` fails, had to change to the drive and folder and use `python setup.py` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have added project folder (RTbatch) as a package in setup.py. Just make sure to have packages list in setup.py contains only python packages (ex: folders with **init**.py).

Hope this fix the issue.